# How to restrict access to /javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf

Tags: jsf-2

From http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/526012:

> Partial Directory Traversal Via Resource Identifier (CWE-22): A defect exists that allows for directory traversal within the
>   application. The directory traversal is limited in that it cannot be used to escape from the application and access arbitrary
>   files on the application server

How to restrict access to below path in JSF 2.0
console/javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf?

Answer (score 1):

This was as per [issue 1166](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/1166) already fixed for long in 2.0.0-b14 (June 2009).

Just make sure that you're using most recent JSF impl/version and that you're **not** using a beta(!) version of a library in production. JSF 2.0 was officially released along with Java EE 6 on December 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Add filter inside this check condition if any request is coming with this value  javax.faces.resource... then throw back with security error.